# Trying to evaluate $\lim\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}\to\infty}\left[n+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\frac{b^{nk}}{b^k-1}\right]$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, summation

I need some help to evaluate this limit :
$$\lim\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}\to\infty}\left[n+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\frac{b^{nk}}{b^k-1}\right]$$
With $b\in\left(1,+\infty\right)$.

If it's not possible to get a closed form for unspecified $b$, then I'd still gladly take any value for any particular case of $b$...

Now this looks like a hard one to me, so I'm curious what people here can get out of it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\frac{b^{nk}}{b^k-1}
= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} b^{(n-j)k}
= \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \left( e^{-b^{n-j}} - 1 \right). $$

Then

\begin{align*}
n + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\frac{b^{nk}}{b^k-1}
&= n + \sum_{j=1}^{n} \left( e^{-b^{n-j}} - 1 \right) + \sum_{j=n+1}^{\infty} \left( e^{-b^{n-j}} - 1 \right) \\
&= \sum_{p=0}^{n-1} e^{-b^{p}} + \sum_{p=1}^{\infty} \left( e^{-b^{-p}} - 1 \right),
\end{align*}

Taking $n\to\infty$, this converges to

$$ \sum_{p=0}^{\infty} e^{-b^{p}} + \sum_{p=1}^{\infty} \left( e^{-b^{-p}} - 1 \right) $$

I will be surprised if this has a closed form in elementary functions.

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't seem like we can go any further...
Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Looking at Sangchul Lee's answer, I very vaguely remember (problem of age !) that, many years ago, one of my PhD students faced a similar problem in statistical thermodynamics. No closed form was found even using special functions and the values were just tabulated.

Rewriting Sangchul Lee's last expression as
$$S(b)=\frac 1 e +\sum_{p=1}^\infty \left(e^{-b^p}+e^{-b^{-p}}-1\right)$$ and computing for successive values of $b$ here are some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2  & -0.33274738243290 \\
 3  & -0.02563211829889 \\
 4  & +0.08370527009108 \\
 5  & +0.14417082789722 \\
 6  & +0.18389984613125 \\
 7  & +0.21207087052753 \\
 8  & +0.23297803691263 \\
 9  & +0.24903012631702 \\
 10 & +0.26170148665894 \\
 11 & +0.27194029136964 \\
 12 & +0.28037846795977 \\
 13 & +0.28745009983337 \\
 14 & +0.29346160695070 \\
 15 & +0.29863473335839 \\
 16 & +0.30313359924031 \\
 17 & +0.30708215624204 \\
 18 & +0.31057572429427 \\
 19 & +0.31368879397943 \\
 20 & +0.31648041901516
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Where does the root of the expression lie I wonder?

Comment: @PeterForeman. $3.17483$ is the root ! Quite close to $\sqrt{10}$. One more coincidence, I bet. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for your help, the fact that it has a root is quite interesting indeed...